# How to use common custom component in some pages? ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

What is the use of this file and how to use it?

file : components.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header';
@NgModule({
declarations: [HeaderComponent],
imports: [],
exports: [HeaderComponent]})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

And How would it help me to implement custom layout for some pages?

Comment: what is the use of what file?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I am asking the similar question. As I generated component. It also created in the name of 'components.module.ts'.

Comment: still not clear !

Comment: Oh kay.. I want to use common layout in some pages.

Comment: the idea is you can import the components.module in any page module and use any of the components instead of declaring in every module. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I am getting this error.  Unexpected module 'ComponentsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.